# Ubuntu Unity (64-bit) Bugs on Nvidia dual screen

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-monitors

On my work computer I have upgraded 10.04 to 10.10 and now to 11.04. Upgrades have mostly worked well and the dual screen setup is almost working. There are however a couple of annoying bugs which I tried to report but the bug reporting tool told me to ask about the bugs here. Here's what I have found:

1. Auto-hide stops working. It doesn't seem to matter which application is maximised/covering the dock, it just stays on top. I have tested changing the autohide settings with no result.
2. Scenario: One maximised window on each screen. If I now try to drag the window that doesn't have focus by dragging the top of the window nothing happens. I can also not give the window focus by clicking the top bar, I have to click inside the window and then I can drag the window. If I unmaximise the window with focus it does work and I can both change focus and drag the window directly by clicking the top of the maximised window.

Any bug fixes coming for these issues?
Any work-arounds?

Comment: Can you split these off into separate questions? The system works best when each post is an individual question.

Comment: The first one sounds like a known bug I'm sure I saw on Launchpad and the second one if it doesn't exists already should be a new bug ticket.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure all this will eventually be smoothed out and fixed. I run a dual monitor setup and have noticed and been annoyed by the exact same things. Just keep in mind that this is a MAJOR revision to an age old window manager and will take some time to iron out all the kinks. I think the race to market between Gnome 3 and Unity may have pushed both development groups to churn out a product that wasn't maybe 100% ready. 11.10 should address most of these issues if not in a patch sooner.

As for the dysfunctional unity launcher, I have reverted to disabling auto-hide at this point but with 2 large LCD's I have room to spare.

As for the focus issue I think it has something to do with the fact that they integrate the title bar into the top panel when a window is maximized. Be patient, my friend.

Sorry for not having a better solution for you. As a last resort I would just default back to the classic gnome desktop if you can't deal with the above stated issues until they are addressed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question is a little unclear.  By "it just stays on top," do you mean the toolbar or dock will not auto-hide?  If you are talking about when the toolbar stops auto-hiding then I can help.  For me, it seems to do this, only on some programs. It happens when I click and drag an object.  For example, moving a file to a folder, then the toolbar will not auto-hide.  I have noticed it with Mendeley Desktop and QtiPlot so far.  To get the bar to return to auto-hide, simply go to a web page, click and drag so text to highlight, then click the highlighted text, hold and drag.  This has worked for me, and others have said it works too.  I hope this helps!  It's weird, I know.  I hope it is addressed too!
2. I am pretty sure that is how the windows are just working in 11.04, and it is just highlighted when using two or more monitors.  I have noticed this effect on my dual setup for my office and home.  Hopefully, it will be addressed, but I have kind of gotten used to it.  Now only if I could get my quad monitors to work!!